# ie does not free memory even when iframe is closed

Tags: iframe

I have 15 iframes in a web page.

```
<iframe id="iframe0" style="left: 1px; visibility: visible; width: 100%; position: absolute; top: 23px; border: 1px solid #8db1e3;" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto"></iframe>
<iframe id="iframe1" style="left: 1px; visibility: visible; width: 100%; position: absolute; top: 23px; border: 1px solid #8db1e3;" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto"></iframe>
<iframe id="iframe2" style="left: 1px; visibility: visible; width: 100%; position: absolute; top: 23px; border: 1px solid #8db1e3;" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto"></iframe>
<iframe id="iframe3" style="left: 1px; visibility: visible; width: 100%; position: absolute; top: 23px; border: 1px solid #8db1e3;" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto"></iframe>
<iframe id="iframe4" style="left: 1px; visibility: visible; width: 100%; position: absolute; top: 23px; border: 1px solid #8db1e3;" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto"></iframe>
<iframe id="iframe5" style="left: 1px; visibility: visible; width: 100%; position: absolute; top: 23px; border: 1px solid #8db1e3;" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto"></iframe>
<iframe id="iframe6" style="left: 1px; visibility: visible; width: 100%; position: absolute; top: 23px; border: 1px solid #8db1e3;" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto"></iframe>
<iframe id="iframe7" style="left: 1px; visibility: visible; width: 100%; position: absolute; top: 23px; border: 1px solid #8db1e3;" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto"></iframe>
<iframe id="iframe8" style="left: 1px; visibility: visible; width: 100%; position: absolute; top: 23px; border: 1px solid #8db1e3;" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto"></iframe>
<iframe id="iframe9" style="left: 1px; visibility: visible; width: 100%; position: absolute; top: 23px; border: 1px solid #8db1e3;" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto"></iframe>
<iframe id="iframe10" style="left: 1px; visibility: visible; width: 100%; position: absolute; top: 23px; border: 1px solid #8db1e3;" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto"></iframe>
<iframe id="iframe11" style="left: 1px; visibility: visible; width: 100%; position: absolute; top: 23px; border: 1px solid #8db1e3;" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto"></iframe>
<iframe id="iframe12" style="left: 1px; visibility: visible; width: 100%; position: absolute; top: 23px; border: 1px solid #8db1e3;" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto"></iframe>
<iframe id="iframe13" style="left: 1px; visibility: visible; width: 100%; position: absolute; top: 23px; border: 1px solid #8db1e3;" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto"></iframe>
<iframe id="iframe14" style="left: 1px; visibility: visible; width: 100%; position: absolute; top: 23px; border: 1px solid #8db1e3;" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto"></iframe>
```

Each of those iframes calls some web pages with huge amount of gridview in .NET.
I am developing these pages using ASP.NET.
Here my problem starts.

I understand that iexplorer.exe is growing up since I load lots of data in these pages.
It goes up to 400MB sometimes.
But the problem is that even if I close the iframe which means...
I make one of those iframes src = about:blank and make it display = none;
However the size of iexplorer.exe's memory does not go down.
It does not free the memory.
How can I let the memory go down to normal?
Actually, I have tested in IE8.
But IE9 seems to be freeing the memory. I am not sure.

**EDIT:**
I close the iframe as velow

```
document.all['iframe' + menuOrder[currentTab]].src = "about:blank";
document.all['iframe'+menuOrder[currentTab]].style.visibility="hidden";
```

Comment: There's really no need. You don't need to free physical memory in order for the operating system to use it for another purpose. And virtual memory is available in nearly unlimited supply and not usually worth the trouble of freeing. If you have an actual problem, other than seeing a number that you don't like, please tell us what it is and we'll help you fix it.

Comment: _"I have 15 iframes in a web page"_.  Sorry bro

Comment: @David Schwartz In fact, my pc is getting slow when the iexplorer.exe spends too much memory. That's the real problem.

Comment: @JoshuaSon: Does the performance remain poor even after you close the iframes?

Comment: @David Schwartz Because, the memory does not go down. Yes, the performance remains poor even after I close the iframe. I edited about how I close the iframe.

Comment: @JoshuaSon: Unless you have an unusual setup, one has nothing to do with each other. Consumption of virtual memory should not impact performance. You're making the issue more confusing by addressing the memory rather than the performance problem. How big is your page file? If the page file is too small, your system can run short on virtual memory even if it has plenty of physical memory.

Comment: @David Schwartz I just need some workarounds to reduce the memory of iexplorer.exe as I close the iframes.

Comment: @JoshuaSon: You don't. You need to solve the performance problem. Consumption of virtual memory should have no significant effect on performance unless you have a busted configuration somewhere. How big is your page file?

Comment: @David Schwartz My page file is 2GB. But my customers keep saying, since they run some web applications in our web site(within iframes), their PC get slower and slower. And they noticed that the size of iexplorer.exe goes up to about 500mb.

Comment: @JoshuaSon: Does your system replicate their performance problems? Or do your customers have performance problems but you only see virtual memory consumption?

Answer (score 1):

Setting visibility to hidden does not "Close" the iframe. It is still there consuming resources even if you can't see it. You might be able to lower the memory usage it you change the page that the iframe is using to a blank page.

Comment: As you can see, I set the blank page to the iframe.